# Align numbered and unnumbered entries in ToC (Koma-Script)

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, koma-script, tocstyle

In Koma-Script I use `\addsec{.}` to add section without numbers.  However, with respect to my ToC this gives undesirable results, as the unnumbered section-title is aligned with the beginning of the ToC line.  How do I make unnumbered section aligned with numbered section in the ToC?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}
\selecttocstyleoption{tocflat}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}
\hrulefill
\section{First section}

\section{Second section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\addsec{A section which should not have a number}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the `tocstyle` package option `toctextentriesindented`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[toctextentriesindented]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}
\selecttocstyleoption{tocflat}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}
\hrulefill
\section{First section}

\section{Second section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\addsec{A section which should not have a number}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry about not reading the manual properly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion that needs at least [KOMA-Script Version 3.20](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) (current on CTAN) but does not use any additional package.

```
\documentclass[toc=indenttextentries,toc=flat]{scrartcl}[2016/05/10]

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocraggedpagenumber,
  toclinefill=\quad
]{part,section,subsection,subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent\hrulefill
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\addsec{A section which should not have a number}
\end{document}
```

[image]